# Net 6.0 Not Showing In Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, .net-6.0

So when i heard Net 6.0 Came out, i was excited, and so i updated Visual studio 2019 to 2022, but when i made a Windows Forms Application (.net), but here's what i saw.

[Lastest Version?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QxLj.png)

And so i was confused, where was the Net 6.0? Where?

4.8? What? And i had absolutely no idea what to do, i searched on google but it all were about 2019, But not 2022.
I Checked if the runtime was installed and it was, if so, why was it not showing?

[Net 6.0 Was runtime was installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDFQL.png)

I just want to code with the latest version, not the oldest ones.

Comment: Wrong project template, you selected "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)".  Which targets the legacy .NETFramework (2.0 through 4.8).  For .NET 6.0 you need "Windows Forms App".

Comment: @HansPassant Like the C# One? There is a bunch of stuff with "Windows Forms App" In Their Name.

Comment: There should be only one that is named "Windows Forms App".

Comment: @PMF The icon has a green text saying "C#" Is it the correct form? (it does not have .net in the name no its just windows form app"

Comment: This is probably the one you want. "C#" is the language, there might be ones called "VB" or "F#", which are different languages. Which one you want is your decision (but C# is by far the most commonly used for .NET development)

Comment: @PMF Alright, Thanks!